# How to get target who are touching on a specific sprite

Tags: javascript, game-engine, phaser-framework

I am trying to make a mini-game by phaser.js. In my idea. A sprite object can collided to a static sprite and continually perform desired effect if they are stick together. However, when I handle them with `this.physics.add.collider`, the callback function just run once.

Search for API document. I find the touching event can be judged by `object.body.touching`. But seen it can only return the facing. So I wonder how to get the object who are touching on the **specific direction** of a sprite? Or the function is need to handle by handy?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not sure if this helps but you should have the direction and position of both sprites, so I guess you have to do it manually, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need more "detailed"/"better" physics functions in phaser, you could use the `matterjs` physics engine.
*(It is as easy as the `arcade` engine, atleast to setup)*

With `matterjs` there are more options, like the "collisions events",  using `matter` you could use the event `collisionactive`.
*([link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Matter.Events.html))*

`collisionactive` executes as long as the two colliding objects touch.

Like this you know the exact object(s) touching. *(And if you need the direction you could find it with the `x` and `y` postions of the objects, or the `velocity` of the impact)*

Here a demo from the offical website, showing `collisionstart` Event https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/physics/matterjs/collision-event

**Here a small with `matter` demo:**

```js
// Minor formating for stackoverflow
document.body.style = "display: flex;flex-direction: column;";  

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 153,
    backgroundColor: '#1b1464',
    physics: {
        default: 'matter',
        matter: {
          debug:true,
          gravity:{y:0, x:0}
        }
    },
    scene: {
        create: create
    }
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

var counter = 0;
var gOverlay;
function create ()
{
    var blockA = this.matter.add.image(50, 80, 'block1');

    var blockB = this.matter.add.image(300, 80, 'block1').setStatic(true);
    var text = this.add.text(10,10, 'Not touching')
    blockA.setVelocityX(3);
    
    
    gOverlay = this.add.graphics();

    this.matter.world.on('collisionstart', function (event, bodyA, bodyB) {
        text.setText(text.text + '\nHIT')
        drawDirectionArrow(bodyA, bodyB)
    });

    this.matter.world.on('collisionactive', function (event, bodyA, bodyB) {
        text.setText(`Touching: ${counter++}`)
        if(counter > 60 ) {
            counter = 0;
            blockA.setVelocityX(-2);
        }
    });

    this.matter.world.on('collisionend', (function (event, bodyA, bodyB) {
        text.setText(text.text + '\nNot touching');
        gOverlay.clear();
        this.time.delayedCall(2000, _ => blockA.setVelocityX(5)); 
    }).bind(this));
}

function drawDirectionArrow(a, b){
  gOverlay.clear();
  
  gOverlay.fillStyle( 0xFF00FF);
  gOverlay.fillTriangle(a.position.x, a.position.y, b.position.x, b.position.y - 10, b.position.x, b.position.y + 10);
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js">
</script>
```

**Update:**
If you need/want to use `arcade` physics, here is a similar demo, with a small workaround using a second `physics-object` to check for overlap.

***Arcade - Physics* workaround - Demo:**

```js
// Minor formating for stackoverflow
document.body.style = "display: flex;flex-direction: column;";  

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 153,
    backgroundColor: '#1b1464',
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {
          debug:true,
        }
    },
    scene: {
        create: create
    }
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

var counter = 0;
var gOverlay;

function create () {
    var blockA = this.physics.add.image(50, 80, 'block1').setOrigin(.5);
    var blockB = this.physics.add.image(300, 80, 'block1').setOrigin(.5);
    
    // Helper
    var blockBx = this.add.rectangle(300, 80, 34, 34);
    
    this.physics.add.existing(blockBx);
    
    blockB.setImmovable();
    
    var text = this.add.text(10,10, 'Not touching')
    blockA.setVelocityX(50);
    
    gOverlay = this.add.graphics();
    
    this.physics.add.collider(blockA, blockB,  function ( bodyA, bodyB) {
        drawDirectionArrow(bodyA, bodyB);
    })
    
    this.physics.add.overlap(blockA, blockBx, function ( bodyA, bodyB) {
        text.setText(`Touching: ${counter++}`);
        if(counter > 60 ) {
            counter = 0;
            gOverlay.clear();
            blockA.setVelocityX(-50);
            text.setText('Not touching');
            this.time.delayedCall(2000, _ => blockA.setVelocityX(50)); 
        }
    }, null, this);
}

function drawDirectionArrow(a, b){
  gOverlay.clear();
  
  gOverlay.fillStyle( 0xFF00FF);
  gOverlay.fillTriangle(a.x, a.y, b.x, b.y - 10, b.x, b.y + 10);
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js">
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your demo. Inspiring from your answer. I think maybe I can achieve it by leavage some overlay function. Adding a invisble effector area around the static object which is actived while sprite collide and touch object on the right driection. But changing physical engine sounds is a far straightforward.

Comment: @李孟昇, I just added for completness a example with arcade physics. :)